# How to protect remote events and function roblox?

Tags: lua, roblox

In my game I have a local script for gun that fires a remote event to change a players health. The problem is that hackers could just fire the remote event and change a players health. How do I stop this from happening? Here's the remote event:

```
script.CHealth.OnServerEvent:connect(function(player,humanoid,amnt)
    humanoid.Health = humanoid.Health - amnt
end)
```

And here's where it's called:

```
game.Workspace.RemoteEvents.CHealth:FireServer(humanoid,60)
```

Comment: Probably you should do some additional checks on server side to determine whether THAT CHARACTER can decrease hitpoints of THAT ANOTHER CHARACTER or not.  For example, if they are too far away from each other you should reject this operation.  Usually, client sends to server a message like the following: "I'm shooting at that direction", and server does all the other work: check who are on the line of fire and how much HP current weapon can inflict (also server can add randomness to this event).

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, NEVER trust the client. You should be doing your damage calculations and rays on the server. So instead of an event to damage a player you should have an event to fire a projectile. Let the server do the security critical work - there's no way to do it otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple answer would just be to make the remote event within the script, and when you're done with it, remove it. Also, never put remote events/functions in workspace, the safest place to put them is replicated storage.

```
local remoteevent = Instance.new("RemoteEvent")
remoteevent.Parent = game.ReplicatedStorage.RemoteEvents
remoteevent.Name = "CHealth"
game.ReplicatedStorage.RemoteEvents.CHealth:FireServer(humanoid,60)
```

For the other script:

```
script.CHealth.OnServerEvent:connect(function(player,humanoid,amnt)
    humanoid.Health = humanoid.Health - amnt
    game.ReplicatedStorage.RemoteEvents.CHealth:Remove()
end)
```

This was just the first way I thought of. I didn't test the script, there may be some spelling errors I didn't catch or something like that, so if there is an error you can always think of that.

If someone hacks with filtering enabled, then fires that event, it will only look like they took damage for them. Also, I think hackers inject server scripts, and server scripts don't work on the client. Here are some good articles: http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=Experimental_Mode | http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=Building_Games_with_Experimental_Mode_Off

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do it is to not have any vulnerabilities with your code. The player can easily exploit that to give them self health, so you should first check if the number is negative (math.sign).

Next, create a randomized key. The best way to do this is to have a key variable set to 0 on the client and a key variable set also to 0 on the server. Create a function on the client that the entire client will use which fires the remote event with that key, but also does something like adds 1 and multiplies it by 100 (or something more complex). Do the same on the server every time a remote is fired. In every event on the server, check if the key provided is the same one as on the server, and if it isn't then kick them. This way, exploiters won't be able to fire remotes without the key which they won't be able to get.